# What would T[, ,] mean in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have the generic-enabled class that is decleared as:

```
public class Image<TColor, TDepth>
      : CvArray<TDepth>, IImage, IEquatable<Image<TColor, TDepth>>
      where TColor : struct, IColor
      where TDepth : new()
   {
      private TDepth[, ,] _array;
```

What would `TDepth[, ,]` mean in this case? That it is just a two-dimensional array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> it is just a two-diminsional array?

Close, but no: it's a 3-dimensional array.

Answer (score 7):

It is a [`Multidimensional Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx). In this case, it has 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

That would be a three-dimensional Array.

Answer (score 4):

that's a 3-dimensional array

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx